# How to send a HEAD request with WebClient in C#?

Tags: c#, header, webclient, head

I'm trying to download just the headers of the response. I wanted to use the HTTP HEAD method like this:

```
var response = client.UploadString(url, "HEAD", string.Empty);
```

Unfortunately this code throws

> ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this
> verb-type.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Consider using HttpClient instead of WebClient.